# Getting a problem after deploy a Django app on Render

Tags: python, django, deployment, render

I developed an app in Django using PostgreSQL as DataBase, on a local environment it works without problems, but when it was deployed on Render.com it the app throws me this error.

I had to set the debug in True to watch the error

[image]

This is that Render console shows me:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "management_notificacion" does not exist
Jun 28 04:55:41 PM  LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "management_notificacion" ...
```

This is the line of code that is given the error, but in local works without problems

context_processors.py

```
from management.models import *

def get_notificaciones(request):
    notificaciones = Notificacion.objects.filter(receptor=request.user.id)[:3]
    no_vistas = Notificacion.objects.filter(receptor=request.user.id, visto=False).count()
    return {
        'notificaciones': notificaciones,
        'no_vistas': no_vistas
        }

def get_mensajes(request):
    mensajes = Mensaje.objects.filter(receptor=request.user.id)[:4]
    no_vistos = Mensaje.objects.filter(receptor=request.user.id, visto=False).count()
    return {
        'mensajes': mensajes,
        'no_vistos': no_vistos
        }
```

If anyone can give a hint to solve this, I'll be so grateful!

Answer (score 1):

The error says that the database table for the Notification model in the management app doesn't exist.  maybe you have to migrate the  management app .

**try :** `python manage.py makemigrations management` .

**then :** `python manage.py  migrate management` .